# Hadoop chain Jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have 4 hadoop Jobs (Job1, job2, job3, job4) with only mapper (reducertasks=0).

When they finish I want to pass all emitted key,values to another job's mapper (job 5).

How can I do it in hadoop 1.0.4? I use new API.

Comment: isn't it simple unless I am missing something severely! Just pass the output paths of all the first 4 jobs as input paths to the 5th job!

Comment: i want to use WholeFileInputFormat in the fifth mapper, so i have to concate first these files... I hope it could be done automatically between these jobs (seperate values pes keys and emmit them to a single mapper per key)...As i see it isnt easy to happen. For example if i have 10 different keys if i concate the files and use WholeFileInputFormat i will have one reduce task, if the files were seperated i could use 10 reduce tasks